# Who is responsible for the drivers on my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I am trying to figure out who is responsible for the graphics drivers on my asus laptop. I have contacted Intel they told me the manufacturer is responsible for the drivers. Then the manufacturer told me microsoft is responsible for the drivers. My question is who is really responsible for the drivers on the laptop the manufacturer, intel or microsoft?

Comment: “Then the manufacturer told me microsoft is responsible for the drivers.”—They might have *enhanced* the truth a little there.

Comment: MFR is responsible for the software that has been placed upon their hardware.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "responsible"? If you're looking to download drivers, you should be able to get that on both the laptop manufacturer's (Asus) website and the GPU manufacturer's (Intel) website

Comment: Who makes the drivers?

Comment: Hmmmm tricky. Microsoft offer many drivers now and many hardware devices can run on the these. However, they're is a difference between running and running as desired. And in some cases at all. So, if suggest you let the devices run as they do until you get an issue. When you get an issue go to manufacturer website for drivers

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach - Intel would release their stock display driver, ASUS would/could/might tweak that drive, then release it to supported devices and operating systems.  Intel does not release a driver that supports the version of the Windows Display Model that Windows 7 supports for your processor.  ASUS can only tweak what they have been provided by Intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer, without a shadow of a doubt, is responsible for the software that has been placed upon their hardware.

They decided what software they would ship it with including what drivers or bloatware it would have pre-installed.

Comment: Does that mean that they have the power to make new drivers for windows 7 with 8th gen processor if they really wanted to.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach - They do not have that capability.  They only tweak the drivers Intel has released.  **Intel's display drivers DO NOT support Windows 7.**  Intel does not release a version of the display drivers, that supports the Windows Display Model, that Windows 7 supports.  **So even if ASUS wanted to tweak the driver to support Windows 7, it would be impossible to do so.**

Comment: Then does that mean that intel has power to make new drivers for windows 7 with 8th gen processor if they really wanted to.

Comment: This may be a better question for law s.e then here. FWIW in terms of NZ law (and probably most law) both the manufacturer and the seller is responsible - the latter because they are who you contracted to.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach They're unlikely to. Windows 7 is soon to be end-of-life. Therefore it will lose support by Microsoft and thus will be obsolete in terms of security to operating systems with continuous updates. And as such, Intel will no longer continue to support it either.

Comment: Also, @davidgo, this question (although it does relate to law through the subject of responsibility), would not fit on Law SE. It's intent is not to determine blame for damages caused by some software or hardware, but to determine who would be the party to request support or updates from. In this case, I do see where you are going, but computation (software and hardware) is best left to IT folks, and law is best left to lawyers.

Comment: @varfirstName As a regular poster on law.se I disagree. The law is a framework which includes defining accountability and obligations of parties(Laws dont blame anyone). The OP asked "who is RESPONSIBLE" and without law the answer would be "no one".  Had  the question been "who writes the drivers" or "who makes the drivers available" then the question would be appropriate here

Comment: You should then know, as a lawman, that instead of accepting a case or question at face value, you should evaluate the phrasing of the subject within the context in which it is being proposed. But please, don't try to lawyer me here. We're just trying to help some guy (or gal) who's got a question about their magic box that makes pretty lights.